# How to call Ionic methods from iOS cordova plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I Need to invoke an ionic method when a call back is fired from iOS native. How can i do this in ionic?

Comment: provide more details ( by adding code ). What you have tried so far and what is the ultimate goal you want to achieve?.

Comment: Make more concise